# how to deal with different ways to write the same thing

Tags: django, postgresql, scrapy

I wanna know if Django has any module to deal with this problem.
I have multiple ways of writing the same city name in a Postgresql database that came from scraping different websites. The field "city name" could be "S. Diego" or "San Diego". My question is if I could have a module that could normalize always to "San Diego" in both situations and I could add some normalization when some new word appear like "S Diego", and maintain this workflow.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use an API to normalize the data you have scraped. Yandex or Google have feature to return a possible list of the location names based on your search query. Get the most possible answer they returned and use it to map your input to the correct one. There are manual mapping features but I highly recommend one of the giants that solved the problem before us.

Comment: But I'm interested in explore a manual mapping, is it possible? what modules do that?

Comment: You can choose that path too. The easiest way that can work is to choose a JSON object/file to translate your input into the correct output (such as Django's translation files). But it will be static and hard to add every possible input to the file. You can also use tools like NoSQL databases, text search engines, etc. Data entry might be easier in these options for you.